# Newtonsoft.Json, Path returned multiple tokens

Tags: c#, json, json.net

For this code:

```
JObject o = JObject.Parse(jsStr);
var sel = o.SelectToken(".items[*].owner");
```

where the `jsStr` is the content of https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=Newtonsoft.Json&sort=stars&order=desc

I'll get the error of

```
Path returned multiple tokens.
```

How to make it works?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `.SelectToken()` method is for querying a single (string) value. You are getting an error because that path matches 60 values, not one.

Instead, use `.SelectTokens()`, which returns an `IEnumerable<JToken>`:

```
var vals = o.SelectTokens(".items[*].owner");
```

Comment: Thanks! Please also take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42304105/. Thx.