# Newtonsoft.Json, How to code generic selection

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Further on with [Newtonsoft.Json, Path returned multiple tokens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42303538/newtonsoft-json-path-returned-multiple-tokens/),

For this code:

```
JObject o = JObject.Parse(jsStr);
IEnumerable<JToken> selEnum = o.SelectTokens(theFilter);
```

where the `jsStr` is the content of https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=Newtonsoft.Json&sort=stars&order=desc, and `theFilter` can be any valid JPATH query string (e.g., `".items"` or `".items[*].owner"`).

How to return the selected as a valid json string?

Comment: So you you want JSON for an array of all the `owner`s in that source JSON?

Comment: Are you just asking for `var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(selEnum);` ?

Comment: Exactly @dbc! I wrote my own for loop and thought that must be silly. :-) should wait a bit more. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you just need `Json.SerializeObject`:

```
var o = JObject.Parse(jsStr);
var selEnum = o.SelectTokens(theFilter);
var newJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(selEnum);
```

This will give you JSON representing an array of all of the `owner` values from the original JSON.

Comment: Sorry @dbc, you are too late :)